# Can't highlight xml syntax with highlight.js

Tags: javascript, html, xml, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to print xml on an html page.

Example:

```xml
<pre><code class="xml">
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <response value="ok" xml:lang="en">
        <text>Ok</text>
        <comment html_allowed="true"/>
        <ns1:description><![CDATA[
        CDATA does <not> escape <tags like="this"></tags></not>.
        ]]></ns1:description>
        <a></a> <a/>
    </response>
</code></pre>
```

I'd like to use [highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/) to highlight code on a page but there's a conflict with xml and html.

I only had success with some php code using `<pre><code class="php"></code></pre>`, haven't tried with other languages. The only way I found to display xml code is in a textarea, but I'd prefer to show the xml with some sweet syntax-highlighting.

I have made a [jsfiddle to illustrate the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/wgBzW/1/).

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should escape angle brackets with `&lt;` and `&gt;` when you want to display them literally. Otherwise you have actual markup within your `<code>` element that browsers try to interpret. This has nothing to do with any JavaScript applied to it.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm, I did not realize it was that simple.

Comment: What's the point, would not be smarter if the library itself take the html and    replace the characters itself. something like. $html= $('pre code').innerHtml(); $parsedHTML = $html.replace("<", "&lt;");$parsedHTML = $html.replace(">", "&gt;"); and then works it's magic and style the st out of that. I think it's lazy not to.

Comment: The point is to let users or other tools to actually use markup in code. Links, background-highlighted lines, stuff like that.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, [Google Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) does render XML blocks properly (without having to encode them as `&lt;`.

Comment: Neither Highlight or Google Prettify managed to show <pre><h1>alkdjf</h1></pre> as expected for me.

Comment: Google Prettyify doesn't.